# RSpec .to be_empty raises ArgumentError "The expect syntax does not support operator matchers"

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, rspec-expectations

I'm using Ruby Cucumber to test an app. One of my step definitions does this:

```
Then(/^all of my (\.\S+) should not have the below fields:$/) do |path,table|
  #path is my api, table is the fields list I'm sending through cucumber feature file and @result is the json resonse
  expect(JsonPath.on(@result.body,path).flatten.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq & table.raw.flatten).to be_empty
end
```

Surprisingly this has started raising an error

```
The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`. (ArgumentError)
```

in one of my new git branches. Even now the main branch does not raise any error for this line of code.

I tried searching for any difference of code in the new branch related to this, but found nothing, not even any change in gem versions.

Here are a few things I tried:

```
puts JsonPath.on(@result.body,path).flatten.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq & table.raw.flatten
#[]
var = JsonPath.on(@result.body,path).flatten.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq & table.raw.flatten
puts var.class
#Array
```

So, my & operation results in an empty array, i.e. [], on which I apply the rspec matcher `.to be_empty`.
The same code with the same values from JSON works in one branch and doesn't in another. This is not a machine related error as the same branch on different machines raises this error.

I even updated my RSpec gem versions on this new branch and tried, but still the error exists. I'm unable to identify the root cause for this failure. Help!

Comment: I don't see a problem in the code you've shown so far. Please include the entire backtrace in your question.

Comment: Do you just want the backtrace of the error ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: I found it. It was because of the "method_missing" method written without calling 'super'. After modifying my method_missing to use super, this issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

> I tried searching for any difference of code in the new branch related
>   to this, but found nothing, not even any change in gem versions.

If it works when you switch back and forth, on different computers, with the same gem versions, then *something* in this diff is causing the problem, regardless of how unlikely you think that possibility is.

Start winnowing down the diff, either using `git bisect` if it's many commits, or by selectively applying the broken diff to the working one until you locate the code that breaks.

As a random guess: are you defining an `empty` method in the broken diff?

Comment: I found it. It was because of the "method_missing" method written without calling 'super'. After modifying my method_missing to use super, this issue got resolved